# Regex ignore tokens that do not start with letter

Tags: java, regex, string, token

how can I write a regex that ignores any token that does not start with a letter? it should be used in java.

example: `it 's super cool` --> regex should match: `[it, super, cool]` and ignore `['s]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative regex:**

```
"(?:^|\\s)([A-Za-z]+)"
```

**Regex in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "it 's super cool";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?:^|\\s)([A-Za-z]+)").matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String result = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
it
super
cool
```

**Note:** To match alphabetic characters, letters, in any language (e.g. Hindi, German, Chinese, English etc.), use the following regex instead:

```
"(?:^|\\s)(\\p{L}+)"
```

More about the class, `Pattern` and the classes for Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties, can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: This answer may be incomplete, depending on what is meant with "token". What separates a token from another? Only tokens consisting ONLY of letters will be recognized as one. The token "doppler-effect" would only yield "doppler" and completely drop "effect".

Comment: `[A-Za-z]` works for only English alphabets. In order to cover all types of letters (e.g. Hindi, German, Chinese etc.), you should use `\\p{L}` in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I did not know that since I never tried regex outside the English alphabet. I will add that info. Thanks Arvind!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?<!\\p{Punct})(\\p{L}+)` which means letters not preceded by a punctuation mark. Note that `(?<!` is used to specify a [negative look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Check the documentation of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to learn more about it.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "it 's super cool";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\p{Punct})(\\p{L}+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
it
super
cool
```